# Difficulty between intents in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I am a beginner and I started by creating a radio app that has many stations but I have one problem.

When I hit "Play" for the radio, it starts playing then I come back to the precedent activity (stations list) and when I come back again to the same radio that is playing and hit "Pause" it diffuses "Not Playing". (I made a toast so that when I hit "Pause" while the radio is not playing it diffuses "Not Playing") but the radio is still "Playing".

Here is the code for the 2 buttons (Play and Pause):

```
btnPlayMFM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (isOnline() == true) {
            if (isPlaying() == false) {

                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(MosaiqueFM.this, "Loading \nPlease Wait", 10000);
                    t.show();

                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream_url);
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                } else if (isPlaying() == true) {
                    Toast t2 = Toast.makeText(MosaiqueFM.this, "Playing", 2000);
                    t2.show();
                }
            }
            if (isOnline() == false){
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(MosaiqueFM.this, "Internet Connection Required", 3000);
                t.show();
            }
        }

    });

    btnPauseMFM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPlaying() == true) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            } else if (isPlaying() == false){
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(MosaiqueFM.this, "Not Playing", 2000);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    });

public boolean isPlaying()  { 
    return(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question to make it more readable, and I noticed you might have an error. You don't close off the `btnPlayMFM.setOnClickListener(` before you do `btnPauseMFM.setOnClickListener`, so you set the listener for the pause button inside the part where you set the listener for the play button.

Comment: Also please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question, as it will go over some of the necessary details to make a question a good question. Something I noticed was the title of your question. It looks like your title doesn't explain your question, rather it explains why you posted your question. Make sure your titles give as much detail about your specific question or problem as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two activities - one more showing stations list and another for play/pause a particular radio station then apparently when you'll leave the second activity , your activity will get destroyed and `mediaPlayer` will become null and so , when you'll come back,  `isPlaying()` will be false.
And that's why you are getting this `Toast`-

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(MosaiqueFM.this, "Not Playing", 2000);
```

**Suggestion** - For these kind of apps, you don't want the radio to stop when the user leaves your app. So I suggest you use service for play purpose.